# Getting first thread id for Facebook XMPP using Asmack

Tags: facebook, xmpp, message, facebook-chat

I am using asmack on Android to talk to Facebook XMPP.

When an incoming message arrives, I get the (XMPP) thread ID from that message/chat. Sending further messages (using that ID) works just fine.

The problem starts when the first message is sent from my application's side. Then I don't have the current thread ID (since they change on the Facebook server). And sending the message does not work. My system sends OK, but it is never registered on Facebook.

So, how do I get the initial (XMPP) thread ID from an inbox chat?

I tried using the graph API to send a message (inbox/comment). But it does not work (you have to be whitelisted... whatever it is).

Please help, how can I initiate an XMPP thread, and not just respond?

Answer (score 0):

Study the one of open source project which used Asmack then you will be get clear idea how its working. [Beem-Project](http://beem-project.com/) is one one of open course project which used Asmack

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Facebook will accept any thread ID you give it. There was a problem in the way I handled new message threads created locally, rather then external created threads (from Facebook). Now everything works, even firing up a thread from my application, using asmack.